# Trigger Onchange event of a dropdownlistFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 dropdownlists: Country, State and City. On change of Country dropdown, state dropdown has to populate for selected country, on change of state dropdown, city dropdown has to populate for selected state.

The fuctionality works when the dropdown values are changed from the UI. Now I want to populate the dropdowns with the selected values stored in the database. ie. If my database has values countryId=1, stateId=5, cityId=2 then my dropdown should populate accordingly. For which the dropdown onchanhge has to call directly when selected value is set to it. But the value is getting set for the first dropdown (country dropdown) but state and city does not set the values as country on change is not triggered.

Here is my code:

**.cshtml**

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>Country</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick"} )
            </div><label id="CountryListLable" style="color:red;"></label>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>State</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <select id="ddState" class="form-control show-tick">
                    <option>-- Please select --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label id="StateListLable" style="color:red;"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>City</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <select id="ddCity" name="ddCity" class="form-control show-tick">
                    <option value="0">-- Please select --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label id="CityListLable" style="color:red;"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
 $('#CountryId').change(function () {
        //alert($(this));
        var cN;
        var UserType = $(this).data('type');

            $('#ddState').selectpicker();
            $('#ddState').empty();
            $('#ddState').selectpicker('refresh');
            $('#ddState').append("<option>-- Please select --</option>");
            cN = $('#CountryId').val();
        if (cN === '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AdminUser/GetStatesForCountry?countryId=" + cN, success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $.each(result, function (key, value) {

                            $('#ddState')
                               .append($("<option></option>")
                                          .attr("value", value.stateId)
                                          .text(value.stateName));
                            $('#ddState').selectpicker('refresh');
                            $('#ddState').selectpicker('val', "-- Please select --");
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#ddState').change(function () {
        var UserType = $(this).data('type');

            $('#ddCity').selectpicker();
            $('#ddCity').empty();
            $('#ddCity').selectpicker('refresh');
            $('#ddCity').append("<option>-- Please select --</option>");
            cN = $('#ddState').val();
        if (cN === '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AdminUser/GetCitiesForState?StateId=" + cN, success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $.each(result, function (key, value) {

                            $('#ddCity')
                             .append($("<option></option>")
                                        .attr("value", value.cityId)
                                        .text(value.cityName));
                            $('#ddCity').selectpicker('refresh');
                            $('#ddCity').selectpicker('val', "-- Please select --");
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Controller code**

```
var countryData = new List<CountryData>();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> countryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
countryData = (List<CountryData>)HttpContext.Cache.Get("countryResponse");
if (countryData == null)
{
    string response = Service.APIHelper_GET(StringConstants.GetCountryDetails);
    if (!response.Equals("Internal Server Error."))
    {
        countryData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<CountryData>>(response);
        HttpContext.Cache.Insert("countryResponse", countryData);
    }
}
countryList = countryData.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.countryName, Value = m.countryId.ToString() });

ViewBag.country = countryList;//new SelectList(countryList);


public JsonResult GetStatesForCountry(int countryId)//get states for countryid = id 
{
    Session["CountryId"] = countryId;
    return Json(getStateList(countryId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public List<State> getStateList(int countryId)
{
    var stateList = new List<State>();
    stateList = (List<State>)HttpContext.Cache.Get("StateResponseForCountry_" + countryId);
    if (stateList == null)
    {
        var response = (List<CountryData>)HttpContext.Cache.Get("countryResponse"); //this wont b null bcz on page load putting country list to chache
        foreach (var item in response)
        {
            if (item.countryId == countryId)
            {
                stateList = item.states;
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Cache.Insert("StateResponseForCountry_" + countryId, stateList);
    }
    return stateList;
}


public JsonResult GetCitiesForState(int StateId)
{
    var cityList = new List<City>();

    cityList = (List<City>)HttpContext.Cache.Get("CityResponseForState_" + StateId);
    if (cityList == null)
    {
        List<State> stateList = getStateList(Convert.ToInt32(Session["CountryId"]));

        foreach (var item in stateList)
        {
            if (item.stateId == StateId)
            {
                cityList = item.cities;
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Cache.Insert("CityResponseForState_" + StateId, cityList);
    }
    return Json(cityList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is the scenario for better understanding of my issue: 
I have a create user page in which user will select from cascaded dropdowns (country, state, city) and save selected valued to database. The problem is in edit user, where I need to populate the dropdowns based on selected values. ie. I need to populate state dropdown with selected values from database.

**UPDATE**
With the help of @Sagar's solution I have managed to set selected value for the country dropdown. But the state and city dropdowns are still not getting set. Here is the updated code:

**cshtml**

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>Country</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick" })
            </div><label id="CountryListLable" style="color:red;"></label>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>State</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick" })
            </div>
            <label id="StateListLable" style="color:red;"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>City</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.fKCityId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick" })
            </div>
            <label id="CityListLable" style="color:red;"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var countryId = $('#CountryId').val();
    getStates(countryId);

    var StateId = $('#StateId').val();
    alert(StateId);/// here I am not getting correct value -- it passes stateId='-- Please select --'
    getCities(StateId);

    $('#CountryId').change(function () {
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        getStates(countryId);
    });

    $('#StateId').change(function () {
        var StateId = $(this).val();
        getCities(StateId);
    });

});

function getStates(countryId) {
    $('#StateId').selectpicker();
    $('#StateId').empty();
    $('#StateId').selectpicker('refresh');
    $('#StateId').append("<option>-- Please select --</option>");

    if (countryId === '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AdminUser/GetStatesForCountry?countryId=" + countryId, success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $.each(result, function (key, value) {

                    $('#StateId')
                       .append($("<option></option>")
                                  .attr("value", value.stateId)
                                  .text(value.stateName));
                    $('#StateId').selectpicker('refresh');
                    $('#StateId').selectpicker('val', "-- Please select --");
                });

            }
        });
    }
}

function getCities(stateId)
{
    $('#fKCityId').selectpicker();
    $('#fKCityId').empty();
    $('#fKCityId').selectpicker('refresh');
    $('#fKCityId').append("<option>-- Please select --</option>");
    if (stateId === '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AdminUser/GetCitiesForState?StateId=" + stateId, success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $.each(result, function (key, value) {

                    $('#fKCityId')
                     .append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value", value.cityId)
                                .text(value.cityName));
                    $('#fKCityId').selectpicker('refresh');
                    $('#fKCityId').selectpicker('val', "-- Please select --");
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your exact problem??

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - your will never get correct 2-way model binding with your current implementation

Comment: @PRABA I want to populate the dropdowns with selected values from database

Comment: @Arti the code your posted not working ya?. I think you already done code for populate the dropdowns with selected values from database. what error you facing in the above code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke My code works fine if the dropdown is changed manually. My problem here is that I want to set the selected values to the cascaded dropdowns.

Comment: Which is why I gave you a link to show you how to do it correctly

Comment: The code above works when dropdown value is changed manually by clicking on the dropdown. I want it to populate the state dropdown with selected value from the database

Comment: Your code shows how to populate cascaded dropdown which I have done already. Here is the scenario : I have a create user page in which user will select from cascaded drop downs and save selected valued to database(working). The problem is in edit user, where I need to populate the dropdowns based on selected values.

Comment: Then you have not bothered to study the code! It is exactly what the code (particularly in the controller methods does). And its all done so it gives correct 2-way model binding (which your code will not do) and client side validation (which your code will not do) and in less lines of code.

Comment: And I have just updated the fiddle - in the `Index()` method there are 3 commented out lines to mimic the values being set from existing database values. Un-comment them one at a time and see the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue with the help of @StephenMuecke comments.

All I had to do was, to populate the dropdowns while passing the model to the view.

Code:

```
Model usersDetail = users.userDetail;
ViewBag.State = getStateList(usersDetail.CountryId).Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.StateName, Value = m.Id.ToString() });
ViewBag.City = getCityList(usersDetail.StateId).Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.CityName, Value = m.Id.ToString() });
return View(usersDetail);
```

and modified .cshtml to populate state and city from viewbag:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>Country</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick" })
            </div><label id="CountryListLable" style="color:red;"></label>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>State</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.State, "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick" })
                @*<select id="State" class="form-control show-tick">
                    <option>-- Please select --</option>
                </select>*@
            </div>
            <label id="StateListLable" style="color:red;"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label>City</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.fKCityId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.City, "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control show-tick" })
                @*<select id="ddCity" name="ddCity" class="form-control show-tick">
                    <option value="0">-- Please select --</option>
                </select>*@
            </div>
            <label id="CityListLable" style="color:red;"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the ajax on change as well as document ready then it will work fine:

Like:

Create Some common function to call it on both ready and change state:

```
function  getCountryStates(countryId){
//your ajax to get states by country 

}

$(document').ready(function () {

    var countryId = $('#CountryId').val();
    getCountryStates(countryId);

});

$('#CountryId').change(function () {

    var countryId = $(this).val();
    getCountryStates(countryId);

});
```

You have to follow the above same process to get cities of selected state.

This will work.

Comment: Thanks Sagar it helped. But Now the state value is not set. I have updated my question with new issue.

Comment: Any hep on the new issue @sagar?

Comment: @Arti please wait trying to understand where you are doing wrong